# Rolling Window and apply: how to use two columns from the window

Tags: python, pandas, regression, apply, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe, I would like to use rolling to extract two columns and perform regression on them(regress the first column on the second one).I have seen that people use `apply` to perform **one** function on the data such as :

```
def multi_period_return(period_returns):
   return np.prod(period_returns + 1) - 1

pr = data.SP500.pct_change() # period return
r = pr.rolling('360D').apply(multi_period_return)
```

My data is :

```
sp500data:
caldt,spreturn,shifted
1962-07-05,0.0056,0.0112
1962-07-06,-0.0112,0.0056
1962-07-09,0.0067,-0.0112
1962-07-10,0.011,0.0067
```

Considering the above code that works great, I am writing:

```
def firstcoef(spdf):
    return sm.OLS(spdf['spreturn'],spdf['shifted']).fit().params[0]

r = sp500data.rolling(window='360D').apply(firstcoef)
```

But the code does not work and I get the errors as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/moham/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    r = sp500data.rolling(window='360D').apply(firstcoef)
  File "C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 2059, in apply
    return super().apply(
  File "C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 1388, in apply
    return self._apply(
  File "C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 586, in _apply
    result = np.apply_along_axis(calc, self.axis, values)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in apply_along_axis
  File "C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 379, in apply_along_axis
    res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 576, in calc
    return func(x, start, end, min_periods)
  File "C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 1415, in apply_func
    return window_func(values, begin, end, min_periods)
  File "pandas\_libs\window\aggregations.pyx", line 1441, in pandas._libs.window.aggregations.roll_generic_variable
  File "C:/Users/moham/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 10, in firstcoef
    return sm.OLS(spdf['spreturn'],spdf['shifted']).fit().params[0]
  File "C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 882, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 991, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 605, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'spreturn'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I want to extract the first coefficient of the regression and have them as a data frame, then plot them. what is the proper way to revise my code?

My desired out put would be something like this:

```
1962-07-05,   0.09
1962-07-06,  0.011
1962-07-09,   0.02
1962-07-10,   0.03
1962-07-11,   0.04
```

The values are the model parameters (actually I want the first model parameter as `params[0]`).

Comment: "_the code does not work_" - please include the full error message.

Comment: @DYZ done.I put the errors there.

Comment: `KeyError: 'spreturn'`. Your example does not contain this column or a reference to it. Track down where you're referencing that column, and you've found your error

Comment: that would be `'column1'`, @PaulH

Comment: right, but the error says `spreturn`. So, run the example until you get the same error and post that traceback.

Comment: I revised  my main code @PaulH

Comment: @PaulH any idea?